# How to find unresolved PR comments quickly in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

In the Pull Requests page in Azure DevOps, if there's one unresolved comment between many, the page would show something like '19/20 comments resolved'. How can I quickly find that one unresolved comment?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Filter comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#filter-comments) function to filter the active comment.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, one has to do this every time when opening a PR. There seems to be no setting to make this the default. Terrible usability.

Comment: Hi, @rettichschnidi, it is a good idea to make this the default. You are welcome to create a suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest).

Comment: Not wasting my time, won't do. Those Microsoft "feedback" platforms are a joke (e.g. [Support non-RSA keys for SSH authentication](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-non-rsa-keys-for-ssh-authentication/365980), [Microsoft sabotages FIDO2 on Firefox](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/67ecb749-d320-ee11-a81d-0022484cae1d))